# scheduleWithFixedDelay() is not working

Tags: java, scheduled-tasks

I created a schedule:

```
private static final ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor EXECUTOR = new ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor(5);

private ScheduledFuture<?> futureScheduler;

this.beatTask = new BeatTask();

futureScheduler = EXECUTOR.scheduleWithFixedDelay(this.beatTask, 10 * 1000, 300, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
```

And inside BeatTask class:

```
public class BeatTask implements Runnable {

   ......

   @Override

    public void run() {
     ......
     // send request to webService.
    }

}
```

but sometime the scheduler does not work, after task is completed, may be in wait for something or anything else!

I am confused in what happen with scheduler.

Comment: Possible reasons: your run method throws an exception, your code has a deadlock, you cancel the scheduled task somewhere, etc.

Comment: No enough information to help you... What BeatTask does in practice ?  How do you know that scheduler is not working ? Do you have logs ? Where and what is the ouput ? ...

Comment: i have some part of log.                                                                                    01-08 00:21:04.406   INFO   BeatTask         57   run                                 OCPP Heart beat sent Sucessfully          (this indicate successfully run).                          01-08 00:26:51.750   ERROR     BeatTask         101  run                               OCPP HeartBeat Failure, reason=javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out. (after this Log Scedular stop.).

Comment: @sunilborad until you provide more details, ideally a complete example that reproduces the problem, we can only make guesses... See: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Hi., its solved... scheduler is stopped due to OutOfMemoryException which is not Handled in catch block. just added Catch(Throwable ex){ }. Now its working properly.  Thanks for Help.